# In Android, how do I get the text on a button to descend vertically?

Tags: android, xml, text

I am trying to get the text within my buttons to descend vertically like below. I'd prefer to have this happen within the main.xml file.

```
M
Y
T
E
X
T
```

I don't want the text to go sideways.

Comment: Have you tried using ``\n`` already? Using texts like ``android:text="t\ne\ns\nt"`` for example?

Comment: Wow! That did the trick. I feel a little stupid for not even thinking of something so obvious. Thank you.

Comment: @harism Post your suggestion as an answer, you should receive credit for being the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "\n" between the letters, that tells the compiler to add a return character between the characters.

Answer (score 0):

A little helper function for this (i have no better idea, then adding the newlines):

```
public static final String rotateString(String str)
{
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
        sb.append(str.charAt(i)).append(i==str.length()-1? "" :'\n');
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And then if you want to use it:

```
yourTextView.setText(rotateString("Hello Text"));
```

At the moment i could only test it on an emulator with 4.0.3, but it seems to work nicely.